# Unable to connect my mobile device to chrome on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: usb, google-chrome, chromium, samsung

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 on my laptop with chrome 39.0.2171.65 and I'm having a hard time connecting my samsung phone device to chrome.

I installed adb and made sure that Ubuntu recognizes the device.

```
> lsusb
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 04e8:6860 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9100 Phone [Galaxy S II], GT-I9300 Phone [Galaxy S III], GT-P7500 [Galaxy Tab 10.1]

> adb devices
List of devices attached 
07247f49    device
```

When I try to detect the device with chrome I get the permission request on the phone, After approving I can see that chrome recognizes the device (e.g GT-I9190) but I get a message asking me to upgrade my chrome.

```
Chrome (40.0.2214.89)
You may need a newer version of desktop Chrome. Please try Chrome 40.0.2214.89 or later.
```

So I tried looking for a newer version of chrome for ubuntu and I couldn't find any.

```
> apt-cache madison chromium-browser
chromium-browser | 39.0.2171.65-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1064 | http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe amd64 Packages
chromium-browser | 39.0.2171.65-0ubuntu0.14.04.1.1064 | http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/universe Sources
```

Doess that mean I cannot connect chrome with my device on Ubuntu ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I faced the same issue trying to debug app on my Nexus 4. I solved this problem by installing Chrome ( not Chromium ) to ensure having the same Major version of my Nexus.

https://www.google.com/intl/en-US/chrome/browser/desktop/index.html

Comment: Thanks man. This is what i eventually did and it worked.